# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages error in composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

in my laravel app I want to enable fcm with laravel-notification-channels
/fcm, this package now uses kreait/laravel-firebase for firebase credentials setup.

First I installed laravel notifications package without issues, with this command:

```
composer require laravel-notification-channels/fcm:~2.0
```

Now, when I try to install laravel-firebase with the following command:

```
composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
```

I get the following composer warning in my commadn prompt:

```
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Using version ^3.0 for kreait/laravel-firebase
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel-notification-channels/fcm 2.1.1 requires kreait/laravel-firebase ^1.3 || ^2.1 -> satisfiable by kreait/laravel-firebase[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel-notification-channels/fcm 2.1.1 requires kreait/laravel-firebase ^1.3 || ^2.1 -> satisfiable by kreait/laravel-firebase[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel-notification-channels/fcm 2.1.1 requires kreait/laravel-firebase ^1.3 || ^2.1 -> satisfiable by kreait/laravel-firebase[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for laravel-notification-channels/fcm (locked at 2.1.1, required as ~2.0) -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/fcm[2.1.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your complete `composer.json` file?

Comment: As `laravel-notification-channels/fcm` depends on `kreait/laravel-firebase`, the second package is already installed. What do you want to achieve by requiring it again?

Answer (score -1):

When running `composer require laravel-notification-channels/fcm:~2.0` the package `kreait/laravel-firebase` is automatically installed as well.

When I now run `composer require kreait/laravel-firebase` it just says

```
composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
Using version ^3.0 for kreait/laravel-firebase
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update kreait/laravel-firebase
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
```

The error is not coming from these two packages.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

composer require kreait/laravel-firebase --with-all-dependencies

My issues is solved by just running that commnad in your terminal

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Did you really face the exact same error message?

Comment: I have issue in the laravel app..my issue was solved just simply running that code in terminal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).